# Задача на циклы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, циклы

Даны два двузначных числа А и В. Из этих чисел составили 2 четырехзначных числа: 
первое число получили путем написания сначала числа А, затем В. Для получения второго числа сначала записали число В, затем А. 
Найти числа А и В если известно , что первое четырехзначное число нацело делится на 99, а второе на 49. (Признаюсь не понял задачу вообще, что делать не представляю, нашел пример с паскаль Кода, переделал под С++ но не понимаю концепции, хотелось бы разобраться а не просто содрать)

```
int numberA;
int numberB;
for (numberA = 10; numberA < 99; numberA++)
{
    for (numberB = 10; numberB < 99; numberB++)
    {
        if(((((numberA * 100) + numberB) % 99) == 0) && (((numberB * 100 + numberA) % 49) == 0))
        {
            cout << "i = " << numberA << "j = " << numberB;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть конечно способ и получше...

Answer (score 2):

Ну все же просто. У вас есть два двузначных числа - как из них составляется четырехзначное? Скажем, из `18` и `25` как получить `1825`? `18` умножить на `100` и прибавить `25`. `А` умножить на `100` и прибавить `B`...

Как проверить делимость числа `N` на `M`? Если остаток от деления `N` на `M` - т.е. `N%M` - равен `0` - значит, делится.

Вот и все. А дальше простой перебор всех возможных вариантов двух двузначных чисел с помощью двух вложенных циклов.

Так понятно?

Answer (score 2):

Числа представить как `ab` и `cd`, где `a,b,c,d` - некие цифры. Если их приписать друг к другу, то получится `abcd` и `cdab`. А `abcd = ab * 100 + cd`, вот программа и проверяет все возможные наборы на делимость.

Однако задачу можно решить устно. Если `abcd` делится на 99, то и `cdab` тоже делится (можно вспомнить признаки делимости на 9 и 11). Поэтому `cdab` содержит множители 7,7,9,11. ИХ произведение даёт 4851, а добавление ещё одного простого множителя вызывает нарушение условия (двузначные числа), поэтому решение единственное 48/51